# cant find the correct provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider

im trying to use Auth provider for the autindication.
i try first with regular ChangeNotifierProvider and it doesnt work.
then i use MultiProvider and it sill doesnt work.
i read anything on the internet and nothing work..
anyone have any idea how to fix it?
i checked all the imports and all fine.
and i have another application that i used the same technic and all work fine..

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import './screens/main_screen.dart';
import './screens/auth_screen.dart';
import './providers/Auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]);
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => Auth(),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (ctx, auth, child) => MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: [
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: [
            Locale("he", "IR"),
          ],
          locale: Locale("he", "IR"),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Loyalty Punch Card For Stores',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(4, 30, 80, 1),
            accentColor: Color.fromRGBO(175, 234, 220, 1),
          ),
          home: auth.isAuth ? MainScreen() : AuthScreen(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Could you include the exception you have?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `main()` method like

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
      [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]).then((_) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}
```

`WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` needs to call this method if you need the binding to be initialized before calling [runApp].

**Why it's not working:**

Because setPreferredOrientations interacting with native code which performs a task asynchronously, so `ensureInitialized()` is used to make sure that you have an instance of the `WidgetsBinding`.

**For more reference:**
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html

Comment: remove  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
      DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    ]); from my App and add above code which I mentioned, and Start application again by killing it.